# Getting templateRef of host component in directive

Tags: angular

**Component1**: I have a component that has ng-template and content under it

```
<ng-template #content><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

**Directive**: In my directive, I am trying to get templateRef, but it's always empty. (Tried in ViewInit and ContentAfterInit both) (I have to pass this template ref to a service in order to open the modal)

```
@ViewChild('content') public templateref: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**Usage**:

```
<app-component1 directive1> <app-anothercomponent>.....<app-component2> .... </app-component1>
```

Is it even possible to get ng-template content in the directive?
Slackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-view-children-y59xnh?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking is how do I get a *TemplateRef* from a *Directive's* host *Component*?

If you know the component's type in advance, then you can reference it directly from the directive:

```
export class Directive1Directive implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(@Host() @Self() private host: Component1Component) {}

  ngAvterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.host.templateRef);
  }
}
```

It becomes more tricky if you don't know the expected host component's type.  The best way to generically inject a host component into a directive is to have that host directive implement a class and provide that component as that class.

You can start by creating a class that has all properties from the host component that you want to reference.  In this case we're just declaring property that exposes the **TemplateRef**.  The only reason why a class is used over an interface is that it reduces the need for using an **InjectionToken**.

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  public templateRef?: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

The only wrinkle in the host component is that we need to a provider is added to its providers array that basically "reprovides" itself under the alias of **BaseComponent**.  The function **forwardRef** is used to create a deferred reference to something declared later.

```
@Component({
  /*...*/
  providers: [{ provide: BaseClass, useExisting: forwardRef(() => Component1Component ) }]
})
export class Component1Component implements BaseComponent {
  @ViewChild('content') public templateRef?: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

The directive is basically unchanged.

```
export class Directive1Directive implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private host: BaseComponent) {}

  ngAvterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.host.templateRef);
  }
}
```

A lot of this answer came from [How You Can Access All Host Component Details Inside the Directive in Angular](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-how-you-can-access-all-host-component-details-inside-the-directive-f728a5fb1182).

Answer (score 0):

If you try getting it in `ngOninit`, you have to declare it as static :

```js
@ViewChild('content', { static: true }) public templateref: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Otherwise it' only avilable after view init (`ngAfterViewInit`). Other than that, it is possible and done very often, so if you have an issue doing it, try making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) showing your issue.

Comment: Doesn't work. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-view-children-y59xnh?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html

Comment: Oh yes my bad, I didn't fully grasp your code. In your case it's not possible : the `#content` belongs to the usage component, and is only accessible in it. The directive does not know what `'content'` is.

Comment: So, there is no way to get  it in my directive?

Comment: Without coupling the component and the directive, or writing heavy code to do it, unfortunately no.